# Copying only formulas (and not values) from a row in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Can someone tell me how to copy and paste only formulas (and not values) from a row and paste it in the rows below?

```vb
Range("A7", Cells(7, iCol)).Copy
Range("A7", Cells(iRow_4, iCol)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
```

I tried this but it is also pasting the hardcoded values in that row which I don't want. Can someone help with this?

Comment: Loop and check if each cell `.HasFormula`, if so copy to the appropriate destination.